# Bad notification for startForeground (Call Recorder API 29)

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a call recorder program.But,
ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL permission removed from api 29, it gives such an error.
My aim, delete codes used by this permission,How can i do?.i dont want incoming our outcoming information. Please help!

My codes:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (!action.equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) &&
                !action.equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            return;
        }

        String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        String extraState = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "PhoneReceiver phone number: " + phoneNumber);
        if (!FileHelper.isStorageWritable(context))
            return;
        if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            App.isOutComming = true;
        }
        if (extraState != null) {
            dispatchExtra(context, intent, phoneNumber, extraState);
        } else if (phoneNumber != null) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, RecordService.class)
                        .putExtra("commandType", Constants.STATE_INCOMING_NUMBER)
                        .putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber));
            } else {
                context.startService(new Intent(context, RecordService.class)
                        .putExtra("commandType", Constants.STATE_INCOMING_NUMBER)
                        .putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber));
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "phone number x:x " + null);
        }
    }
```

But When I lounch this application,i see this error :

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 number=0 vis=PRIVATE semFlags=0x0 semPriority=0 semMissedCount=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create Notiication channel for android.O

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val importance = android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
            val mChannel = NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance)
            mChannel.description = CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION
            mChannel.enableLights(true)
            mChannel.lightColor = Color.RED
            mChannel.enableVibration(true)
            val mNotificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as android.app.NotificationManager
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
        }
```

and when creating notificiation you should give it the channel id

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
```

Comment: i have such a code //  startForeground(1, new Notification());

Comment: Did you try to give the notification the channel id  NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)

Comment: im a new developer :) .i don't know how to do it. but i will learn thanks

Comment: notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                getActivity())
                .setContentTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setTicker("fgfgf")
                .setContentText(getActivity().getString(R.string.record_enabled))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_notification)
                .setLargeIcon(notificationLargeIconBitmap)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .build();

Comment: Read this blog https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-o-how-to-use-notification-channels--cms-28616